# Что нужно для сборки кода?

Tags: gcc, linux

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main () {
    int descriptor;

    if (descriptor = shm_open("custom", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0)) {
        close(descriptor);
        shm_unlink("custom");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

запуск

```
$ gcc sample.c
```

выдает ошибки

*sample.c:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to 'shm_open'

sample.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to 'shm_unlink'*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
$ gcc sample.c -lrt
```

Comment: А что это за ключ? В справке не нашёл
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.4.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize%20Options